# Why are only some of these links clickable on this document?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ms-word, qlpreviewcontroller

### TL;DR

Why do my custom url scheme links only work if they are appended with Microsoft's hidden bookmark _GoBack_GoBack?

---

### Background

Because [links aren't clickable on PDFs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10810637/916299) displayed in a `UIWebView` or a [`QLPreviewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/QLPreviewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/QLPreviewController), I was experimenting with using Word documents instead.

I discovered that normal `http` and `mailto` links work fine, but I've discovered a peculiarity when using custom url schemes.

While editing, Microsoft Word appends hidden bookmarks for it's own reference as you're navigating. [One such bookmark](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-word/how-to-save-an-ms-word-2010-document-without-the/7c98753b-425b-40c5-a95f-e73f1c6f99e8) is "_GoBack". This is input at the last place you typed.

### Issue

The Word document I have created for my test looks like this:

[image]

With the following hyperlinks underneath:

[image]

When I load this document in my iOS app in a QLPreviewController, only the last link that I edited is clickable, and it seems to be due to the presence of the "_GoBack" as this information has been appended to the end of my link

[image]

Where long clicking on the last link produces open url action sheet. The other links seem to just be treated like normal text:

[image]
[image]

--

Not that I thought it would, but appending the `_GoBack` manually to links doesn't work.

[image]

--

### Question

Has anybody got even the slightest idea what's going wrong?